# Why not call onActivityResult in Activity on Android

Tags: java, android, service

In my application i want a **Recording Screen** and for this I write below code.
After running application, there's no call to my Recorder service and after using `Log.e` it still does not show me logs?
I write **Recording** code into `onActivityResult`.

For this I used `countDownTimer` and I want, when this timer has **finished**, for the recording to start.

For checking if it works I used `Log.e` and it shows a log into `onFinished` code (for timer), but **does not show** any `log`s into `onActivtyResult` code

**My Activity code:**

```
public class RecordingActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private TextView txtTesterCounter;
    Thread thread;
    private int counter;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tester_tutorial_count_down);

        init();

        reverseTimer(4).start();
        //Create video direction
        createDir();
    }

    private void init() {
        txtTesterCounter = findViewById(R.id.txtTesterCounter);
        counter = 3;
        //Acquiring media projection service to start screen mirroring
        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    }

    private CountDownTimer reverseTimer(int second) {
        return countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(second * 1000, 1000) {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (millisUntilFinished <= 800) {
                    onFinish();
                } else {
                    int second = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    txtTesterCounter.setText(App.enToFa(second + ""));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (mMediaProjection == null && !isServiceRunning(RecorderService.class)) {
                    //Request Screen recording permission
                    startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORD_REQUEST_CODE);
                    Log.e("RecordingLog","OnFinished");
                } else if (isServiceRunning(RecorderService.class)) {
                    //stop recording if the service is already active and recording
                }
                finish();
            }
        };
    }

    //Create application directory
    public static void createDir() {
        File appDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + ConstKeys.APPDIR);
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && !appDir.isDirectory()) {
            appDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    private boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.e("RecordingLog","OnActivityResult");
        //The user has denied permission for screen mirroring. Let's notify the user
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && requestCode == ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORD_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }

        Intent recorderService = new Intent(this, RecorderService.class);
        recorderService.setAction(ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORDING_START);
        recorderService.putExtra(ConstKeys.RECORDER_INTENT_DATA, data);
        recorderService.putExtra(ConstKeys.RECORDER_INTENT_RESULT, resultCode);
        startService(recorderService);
        Log.e("RecordingLog","Recorder Service");
    }
}
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: use debug to get the problem. maybe your ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORD_REQUEST_CODE not coming to onactivityresult.

Comment: What is the `finish` method that is called in `onFinish`?

Comment: @DeepakRor, how can i fix it? can you help me?

Comment: @faranjit, because i want when finished timer, close current activity\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onActivityResult` called when the child activity is finished. In your case after you start an activity, you finish the `RecordingActivity`.

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    if (mMediaProjection == null && !isServiceRunning(RecorderService.class)) {
        //Request Screen recording permission
        startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORD_REQUEST_CODE);
        Log.e("RecordingLog","OnFinished");
    } else if (isServiceRunning(RecorderService.class)) {
        //stop recording if the service is already active and recording
    }
    finish(); // what does this method do?
}
```

I assume that **finish** method finished your activity. If it does so, `onActivityResult` will never be called because you finish parent activity.

Comment: i want when finish timer, finish activity

Comment: But also you want `onActivityResult` to be reachable. Choose one! If you finish `RecordingActivity` after timer finishes `onActivityResult` will not be called.